# create columns for every row in multiple dataframes that matches a (sub-)string & merge to another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am reading data from an xlsx file with pandas - and am creating a dataframe for every workbook found in the xlsx file and contains data about peoples jobs, peoples education and peoples previous working experience for example. so I am working with around 13 dataframes at the end.
all the dataframes have a column 'talent_id' in common by which they could be merged (joined) at some later point. the problem I currently face is, that in df1 the talent_id is unique, in df2 the 'talent_id' is not unique due to the fact that people might have had multiple educations in the past (so every job they had previously is an observation), same with df3 that gives me all the previous working experience for each individual 'talent_id'.

SO what I try to achieve is in the end, have one df that holds all the information from df1, df2 and df3 without duplicated 'talent_id' rows, rather 1 row per 'talent_id' and columns for all the educational organization and the former employers as columns or features.

Here is the code to generate the df's - I messed around with melt(), join(), merge() giving me not what I wanted.

Needless to say that not every talent_id has the same amount of educational enteries, some attended 2 schools some 2 schools and 3 colleges etc so the number of features varies, so does the number of previuos working experience.

```
data1 = [['001', '1975-01-01', 'mr', 'de', 'at', 40000], ['002', '1980-01-01', 'mrs', 'en', 'uk', 50000], ['003', '1985-01-01', 'mr', 'es', 'es', 45000]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['talent_id',  'birthdate', 'salutation', 'nationality', 'country', 'salary'])
 
data2 = [['001', 'groundschool_a', 'NaN', 'basic', 'none', 'yes'], ['001', 'high_school', 'math', 'higher', 'none', 'no'], ['002', 'groundschool_b', 'NaN', 'basic', 'none', 'yes'],
        ['002', 'highschool', 'science', 'higher', 'yes', 'yes'], ['002', 'college', 'medicine', 'degree', 'MA', 'yes'], ['003', 'NA', 'none', 'dont know', 'none', 'NaN']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['talent_id',  'schoolname', 'subject', 'type_of_education', 'degree', 'completed'])

data3 = [['001', 'company_a', 'supervisor', 'manufacturing'], ['001', 'company_b', 'editor', 'educational'], ['002', 'company_c', 'clerk', 'pos'],
        ['002', 'company_d', 'cleaning', 'steel'], ['002', 'company_e', 'ceo', 'sales'], ['003', 'company_f', 'it', 'retail']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns = ['talent_id',  'company', 'position', 'industry'])
```

The diserable outcome would be ideally something like this:

```
data4 = [['001', '1975-01-01', 'mr', 'de', 'at', 40000, 
          'groundschool_a', 'NaN', 'basic', 'none', 'yes', 'high_school', 'math', 'higher', 'none', 'no', 
          'company_a', 'supervisor', 'manufacturing', 'company_b', 'editor', 'educational', 'NA','NA','NA','NA','NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'], 
         ['002', '1980-01-01', 'mrs', 'en', 'uk', 50000, 
          'groundschool_b', 'NaN', 'basic', 'none', 'yes', 'highschool', 'science', 'higher', 'yes', 'yes', 'college', 'medicine', 'degree', 'MA', 'yes',
          'company_c', 'clerk', 'pos', 'company_d', 'cleaning', 'steel', 'company_e', 'ceo', 'sales'], 
         ['003', '1985-01-01', 'mr', 'es', 'es', 45000, 'NA', 'none', 'dont know', 'none', 'NaN',
          'company_f', 'it', 'retail', 'NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']]


df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4, columns = ['talent_id', 'birthdate', 'salutation', 'nationality', 'country', 'salary', 
                                    'schoolname_1', 'subject_1', 'type_of_education_1', 'degree_1', 'completed_1', 
                                    'schoolname_2', 'subject_2', 'type_of_education_2', 'degree_2', 'completed_2',
                                    'schoolname_3', 'subject_3', 'type_of_education_3', 'degree_3', 'completed_3',
                                    'company_1', 'position', 'industry',
                                    'company_2', 'position', 'industry',
                                    'company_2', 'position', 'industry'])
```

[image: desired df outcome]

I thought of parsing every df for a specific 'talent_id' write it to a list and in the end make a df out of that list but is there a smarter, more efficient way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

First craft a little helper function to rework your dataframes 2 & 3:

```
def group_pivot(d):
    d =(d.assign(group=d.groupby('talent_id').cumcount())
         .pivot(index='talent_id', columns='group', values=d.columns[1:])
        )
    d.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, c)) for c in d.columns]
    return d.reset_index()
```

example on df3:

```
>>> group_pivot(df3)
  talent_id  company_0  company_1  company_2  position_0 position_1 position_2     industry_0   industry_1 industry_2
0       001  company_a  company_b        NaN  supervisor     editor        NaN  manufacturing  educational        NaN
1       002  company_c  company_d  company_e       clerk   cleaning        ceo            pos        steel      sales
2       003  company_f        NaN        NaN          it        NaN        NaN         retail          NaN        NaN
```

Then merge all transformed dataframes on "talent_id":

```
df1.merge(group_pivot(df2), on='talent_id').merge(group_pivot(df3), on='talent_id')
```

output:

```
  talent_id   birthdate salutation nationality country  salary    schoolname_0 schoolname_1 schoolname_2 subject_0 subject_1 subject_2 type_of_education_0 type_of_education_1 type_of_education_2 degree_0 degree_1 degree_2 completed_0 completed_1 completed_2  company_0  company_1  company_2  position_0 position_1 position_2     industry_0   industry_1 industry_2
0       001  1975-01-01         mr          de      at   40000  groundschool_a  high_school          NaN       NaN      math       NaN               basic              higher                 NaN     none     none      NaN         yes          no         NaN  company_a  company_b        NaN  supervisor     editor        NaN  manufacturing  educational        NaN
1       002  1980-01-01        mrs          en      uk   50000  groundschool_b   highschool      college       NaN   science  medicine               basic              higher              degree     none      yes       MA         yes         yes         yes  company_c  company_d  company_e       clerk   cleaning        ceo            pos        steel      sales
2       003  1985-01-01         mr          es      es   45000              NA          NaN          NaN      none       NaN       NaN           dont know                 NaN                 NaN     none      NaN      NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  company_f        NaN        NaN          it        NaN        NaN         retail          NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I ran some tests with the helper function you came up with - it seems to work nice - currently I run this on a sample dataset with 500 rows and it is pretty fast. the production dataset contains roughly 40k rows - will be looking forward to it ... appreciate your time and effort helping me out ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupby` method following the `agg` to create list out of variables such as education in your example. For instance:

```
df2.groupby('talent_id').agg({
   'education':list
    })
```

This will make the `talent_id` unique and stores everything as a list for you to join. Later you can use appropriate tools such as expanding it into columns of exploding them for your analysis or expectations.

***Note:*** Method `groupby` makes the `talent_id` an index so use the appropriate options in the `merge` method to merge your data frames together.